# Devstack installation: demo tenant name

Tags: openstack

When I install Openstack using Devstack, sometimes the tenant name of **admin** is **demo** and another time it is **admin**. How could this happen?

Answer (score 0):

By default, devstack sets up two tenants - admin and demo. If you log in to Horizon as admin, it might choose either tenant as the current one. But you can always switch between them.

The demo user can only log in to the demo tenant.